# Slideshow JQuery Erro ao passar Slide

Tags: javascript, jquery

## Problema

Tenho um slideshow onde tenho que mostrar duas div's cada vez.
Até a principio pega as duas tudo certo, porém assim que ele retornar a div 1 e 2 no próxino 'next' que eu der a `div 1` continua ali e somente a `div 2` muda para a `div 4`.
A `div 1` deveria mudar para `div 3`.

#### Modelo do slideshow

http://jsfiddle.net/5gfoufLa/1/

#### Acho

Já revisei esse meu código várias vezes e acredito que esteja com a lógica correta e eu tenha de alguma forma alterado o valor da div 1 para um valor que nao consiga existir ou dar o .show().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Linha 37

`$slideativo1 = $slideshow.find("li.slideatualUltimo").next();`

Quando o código é resetado esta sendo definido duas vezes a variável `$slideativo1`.

Remove essa parte que vai funcionar.

Comment: Funciono certinho! Obrigado.